# Как получить значение переменной отправленной из node.js на странице созданной через express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Собственно, нужно получить название трека из группы ВК типа "Исполнитель - Название трека" по ссылке, например http://localhost:3000/soundname, название я получаю из группы, а вот как обновить название "в ссылке", первый раз удается получить, а вот обновить не выходит, причину не могу понять.

```
function getVKAudio() {
    try {
        VKApi({
            token: config['VK'].access_token
        }).then( (data) => {
            data.call( 'groups.getById', {
                group_id: 'name',
                fields: 'status'
            } ).then( (data) => {
                // console.log( data );
                if( data[0].status_audio ) {
                    var audio_name = data[0].status_audio.artist+ ' - ' +( data[0].status_audio.title ).replace( /\[(.*?)\]/g, '' );
                    if( current_track_id == null || current_track_id !== data[0].status_audio.id ) {
                        current_track_id = data[0].status_audio.id;
                        // console.log( audio_name, current_track_id );
                        // client.say( client.opts.identity.username, 'Сейчас играет: ' +String(audio_name) ).catch( console.error );
                        // client.action( client.channels[0], "Сейчас играет: " +String(audio_name) ).catch( console.error );
                        console.log( "Сейчас играет: " +String(audio_name) );
                        try {   
                            app.get( '/soundname', (req, res) => {
                                console.log( String(audio_name) );
                                // console.log( '/soundname ' +String(audio_name) );
                                res.send( String(audio_name) );
                            } );
                        } catch(e) {
                            console.log( '[express] ('+e+')' );
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        if( getVKAudioTimer ) {
            clearTimeout( getVKAudioTimer );
            getVKAudioTimer = setTimeout( getVKAudio, 20000 );
        } else getVKAudioTimer = setTimeout( getVKAudio, 20000 );
    } catch(e) {
        console.log( '[getVKAudio] ('+e+')' );
    }
}
```

Comment: расскажи, пожалуйста, что присходит в строке `app.get( '/soundname', (req, res) => {` и ниже, в рамках блока

Comment: Если честно, я толком не знаю, с express не работал, но вроде как этот метод вызывается при переходе по ссылке?